# Crear una columna si se cumple una o más de una una conidciones de otras de las columnas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo un dataframe con columna de fecha, banco y saldo:
a) en funcion del banco que se trate la comision sobre el saldo es un porcentaje de ese saldo
b) en funcion del banco y entre dos fechas distintas la comision sobre el saldo es otro porcentaje

Simplificado el dataframe seria:

FECHA           Banco        saldo

30/04/2020       Galicia        3000

30/05/2020        Rio           4582

la salida debe ser una columna "comision":

si es de banco galicia, la comision es: saldo * 0.25/100
si de Rio y antes del 01/01/2011 la comision: es saldo * 0.22/100

tengo problemas con if condicion else

Comment: Podrias añadir algo de codigo para que podamos partir de ahi a ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Como es DataFrame, directamente puedes eliminar la fecha con la funcion

```
df.col.str.replace(text,"")
```

Comment: El esta preguntando por las condiciones, no por obtener los datos.